# Display comments with sinatra

Tags: sinatra

I started a micro blogging app with Sinatra for class but for some reason I can not get the posts for my blog to show on the page. If any one can help it would be greatly appreciated. I don't know if I'm missing code or if I wrote  piece of code incorrectly. Thanks again

```
get "/post/new" do
  erb :new_post
end

post "/post/new" do
  p '++++++++++++++++++++'
  @post = Post.new(text: params[:text],
               user_id: session[:user_id])
  if @post.save
    flash[:notice] = "Post has been added"
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Your post was not created, please review and resubmit."
  end 
  redirect "/"
end

 get "/posts" do
  current_user
  @posts = Post.all

  erb :posts
end
```

Comment: Do you have the `posts.erb` you can share?

Comment: The issue is probably in your view (posts.erb). Check that you are indeed outputting your post data using '<%= %>' and not simple evaluating using '<% %>'.